# Rspec shows Undefined method but the object is available in the same block

Tags: ruby, rspec

This works in a tutorial on rspec:

```
class Card
  attr_reader :rank, :suit

  def initialize(rank, suit)
    @rank = rank
    @suit = suit
  end
end

RSpec.describe Card do
  let(:card) {Card.new('Ace', 'Spades')}

  it 'has rank and rank can change' do
    expect(card.rank).to eq('Ace')
    card.rank = 'Queen'
    expect(card.rank).to eq('Queen')
  end
  it 'has suit' do
    expect(card.suit).to eq('Spades')
  end
end
```

But it does not work in the live code. When I run rspec, I get:

```
NoMethodError:
   undefined method `rank=' for #<Card:0x007fdddf8d2420 @rank="Ace", @suit="Spades">
```

Would it be a version/deprecation issue? I am using rspec: 3.8.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error complains about a method `rank=` undefined. Note that this is different from `rank`. Use `attr_accessor` to define both getter and setter methods

```
attr_accessor :rank, :suit
```

This is going to define

```
def rank
  @rank
end

def rank=(r)
 @rank = r
end
```

and the same for `suit`

Comment: Shoot. I forgot I'm writing. Nice. thanks a lot

Comment: My pleasure man